# Adding rows with quarters - filling gaps

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I add the missing quarters between two quarters? I have a table dbo.calendars with all quarters since 2000. And another table with the ids and the quarters. Example of dbo.calendars: 200001,200002,200003,200004,200101,....

I want to fill the gap for the id P206M02117.
The id P206M02118 is right because there are no gaps between quarters.

```
My wrong output
id           qtr
P206M02117  200601
P206M02117  200604
P206M02118  200604
P206M02118  200701
P206M02118  200702

Output I want
id           qtr
P206M02117  200601
P206M02117  200602
P206M02117  200603
P206M02117  200604
P206M02118  200701
P206M02118  200702
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**[Edited to help with the modified question]**

It's not clear how `id` is populated when the row for a quarter is not present; the query below assumes it's populated with the `max(id)` in those cases.

You can do:

```
select x.id, c.qtr
from calendars c
left join (
  select id, min(qtr) as minq, max(qtr) as maxq from t group by id
) x on c.qtr between x.minq and x.maxq
where x.id is not null
```

Result:

```
 id           qtr    
 ------------ ------ 
 PM206M02117  200601 
 PM206M02117  200602 
 PM206M02117  200603 
 PM206M02117  200604 
 PM206M02118  200604 
 PM206M02118  200701 
 PM206M02118  200702
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5907a81c1d1831793152aa6e3b023657).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am getting the error: An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference

Comment: It seems you may be running a [slightly] different version of the query. Please post a fiddle that shows the error.

Comment: I'm trying to replicate the same behaviour on fiddle, but my query is like this select  c.YR_QTR 
    from #TEMP_BASIS_YR_QTR c
    left join #TEMP_ESTADO_SUBPROCESSO cs
    on cs.DT_TRIMESTRE_CONTABILIZACAO = c.YR_QTR
    WHERE  c.YR_QTR between (select min(YR_QTR) from #TEMP_ESTADO_SUBPROCESSO)
                and (select max(YR_QTR) from #TEMP_ESTADO_SUBPROCESSO)
    order by c.YR_QTR

Comment: question edited.

Comment: @Wiz See edited answer.